# XML parse Error javascript servlet

Tags: java, javascript, xml, servlets

I have a simple servlet application that sends XML response to JavaScript.
When I check in my Firebug, This resposonse is received by JavaScript as

```
<valid> AT&T,0.51851370625875,0.97944711419669,Verizon,0.47641942539114,0.99005717081381,wifi,0.48596657869633,0.88912486160201 </valid>
```

Which is a perfectly valid XML response - but Firebug also shows XML error

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: moz-nullprincipal:{30f70c51-7f01-48b4-9f69-4f0093e02ba6} Line Number 1, Column 12:
<valid>AT&T,0.51851370625875,0.97944711419669,Verizon,0.47641942539114,0.9900571...
```

It shows the error at the first comma - which does not makes sense at all. I even tried replacing commas with spaces - but even that gives same problem.

I generate my response from Servlet by

```
String ret="";

for (int i=0; i < ping.size(); i++)
{

    ret += ping.get(i) ;
    if(i != ping.size()-1){
        ret += ",";
    }                   
}

response.setContentType("text/xml");           
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

response.getWriter().write("<valid>"+ret+"</valid>");
```

And in my JavaScript, I  try to retrieve data as

```
var message = xmlHttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("valid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I have use this exact same approach before - not sure why is this not working anymore. 
All I need to do is store the values `(AT&T,0.51851370625875,0.97944711419669,Verizon,0.47641942539114,0.99005717081381,wifi,0.48596657869633,0.88912486160201)` in a javascript array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please indent code with four spaces, as it says in the help section.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the & in AT&T.  You have to escape out that character not the comma.

The reason you get the error at the first comma is that it's trying to parse &T as an html character.

The replace should be `&#38;` for an ampersand

Answer (score 0):

As said, this isn't valid XML. The `&` is a special character in XML.

You want to use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeXml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) to escape special characters in XML. First download [commons-lang-2.6.jar](http://apache.ziply.com//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang-2.6-bin.zip), drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and replace the last line of your servlet as follows:

```
response.getWriter().write("<valid>" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(ret) + "</valid>");
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your `String` concatenation loop with `+=` is pretty inefficient. Consider using `StringBuilder` instead.